# PHP:Defing a global scope variable

Tags: php

I am in a situation .

My php folder structure is like

```
UI
  user
    login.php
    logout.php
  jquery
    somejs

  css
    somecss
blah.php
blah.php
```

Now to import any css ,js or any php file i am using the file path like

```
localhost/UI/user/index.php  // example
```

Now i am trying to define a global variable on any page like

```
 <?php
    $somevar = "localhost";
    GLOBAL $somevar;
    ?>
```

So that i could import any css js like

```
<?php echo $somevar ;?>/UI/user/index.php  // example
```

Problem : It is working on that page only where i declared the variable as GLOBAL

I want to use the variable on each page and don't want to use include

Is there any other alternative to define a variable for files folder in php  ?

Comment: do let me know if any clarification is required

Comment: well, one possible hack is to mess with php.ini. But it's a **hack**. You'd better just `include` your file everywhere. Or, even better, do not use global variables. I would create some kind of `ModuleLoader` helper class, include it everywhere and just let it manage those imports. Or even better, use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not **declare** variable with `global`. You just make it available within you method or function body even it was set (or using your terminology "declared") outside of it. So there's no way to have the variable unless it is declared. And there's no way to do that without running the PHP code (*simplification*, but it does not matter here). And code is not coming from nowhere, hence the need of `include` or `require` of said code that sets variable.

You may try to use `php.ini`'s `auto_include_file` to have your variables auto-included, but still, the PHP code needs to be used for that.

But you generally doing it wrong. move all global variables into class, set autoloader and access i.e. statically. The code will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my experience says .. global is used for accesing variables inside the function those which defined outside the function. 
There can be many different solutions to the same, one i will suggest is use sessions or cookies. Store the data in session / cookies and access it across wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special PHP-defined $GLOBALS array. The $GLOBALS array is an associative array with the name of the global variable being the key and the contents of that variable being the value of the array element. Notice how $GLOBALS exists in any scope, this is because $GLOBALS is a superglobal

You may not need to define a global variable to apply the css, js or any static files viz Images etc to your application. you may use relative path to include js and css files. You can refer to [this article](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/absolute-path-and-relative-path-file-inclusion-in-php.html)   to know more about relative and absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `define()` function for this purpose

```
config.php
<?php
define("host", "localhost");
?>
```

now include this page wherever you want to access `HOST` variable.

you can access this variable like this `echo host;`